# When is the Disk Utility external HD Backup usable as a restore point?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, backup, restore

My Mac just had a white screen and disk repairs have been coming back with disk cannot be repaired. I was able to complete a Disk Utility backup to an external hard drive.

Is this usable as a restore point if the Mac HD seems to be corrupted and suggests it cannot be repaired?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't trust an image made on a failing HDD as a restore point, only as a means of getting specific User Data after replacing the HDD and doing a clean install of the OS. You should also have been keeping Time Machine backups all along the way while using the computer, and if not, then start doing so after replacing HDD and clean install.